# What's the difference between FilterWriter and Writer in Java?

Tags: java, api, io

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterWriter.html, I find that `FilterWriter` is an abstract class, which extends `Writer` and has no extra mothods.

I just wonder:

1. **What is the rationale to define** `FilterWriter` **as an exact copy of** `Writer`?
2. **What's the difference between** `FilterWriter` and `Writer` **?**

Comment: "*...  provides default methods ...*"

Comment: It isn't an exact copy of `Writer`. See the Javadoc. See specifically the constructors, and what it *says* about the methods in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is the rationale to define `FilterWriter` as an exact copy of `Writer`?

`FilterWriter` is *not* an exact copy of `Writer`.  Although declared `abstract`, it provides implementations of all of `Writer`'s abstract methods, and it overrides some of the concrete methods.  These implementations serve `FilterWriter`'s specific purpose, as described in its API docs:

> The abstract class FilterWriter itself provides default methods that pass all requests to the contained stream. Subclasses of FilterWriter should override some of these methods and may also provide additional methods and fields.

The class is abstract, despite having no abstract methods, because the functionality described is not directly useful by itself.  It is intended to serve as a base class for classes that monitor or modify the character stream as it is written to the underlying `Writer`.

> 2. What's the difference between `FilterWriter` and `Writer`?

Functionally, `FilterWriter` provides concrete implementations for `Writer`'s abstract methods, and it overrides a few others.  Type-wise, `Writer` is a superclass of a bunch of classes that `FilterWriter` is not a superclass of, including `FilterWriter` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `FilterWriter` class is the superclass of all of the writer classes that filter output. A subclass of `FilterWriter` works by wrapping an existing writer, called the underlying writer, and providing additional functionality. The methods of `FilterWriter` simply override the methods of `Writer` with versions that call the corresponding methods of the underlying writer.

`FilterWriter` cannot be instantiated directly; it must be subclassed. An instance of a subclass of `FilterWriter` is constructed with another `Writer` object. The methods of a subclass of `FilterWriter` should override some methods in order to extend their behavior or provide some sort of filtering.

`FilterWriter` is like `FilterOutputStream`, except that it deals with a character stream instead of a byte stream.

Comment: The Java Writer class (java.io.Writer) is the base class for all Writer subclasses in the Java IO API. A Writer is like an OutputStream except that it is character based rather than byte based. In other words, a Writer is intended for writing text, whereas an OutputStream is intended for writing raw bytes.

Comment: there are many writers which one are you trying to ask give us an example